# How to get row index in material table Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox, material-table

How to get row index in material table angular

```
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">                                                                            
   <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"                                                                                
     (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null;isSomeSelected()"                                                                               
     [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">                                                                           
 </mat-checkbox></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.ts` define `index` as a property of `RowModel`.

Then you can access it with `row.index` in template and controller.

`.ts`:

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'item1', index: 0},
  {position: 2, name: 'item2', index: 1},
  {position: 3, name: 'item3', index: 2},
];
```

`.html`:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">                                                                            
  <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"                                                                                
                (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null;isSomeSelected()"                                                                               
                [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">                                                                       
  </mat-checkbox>
  <span>{{row.index}}</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare index like this **let i = index**:

```
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row;let i = index">                                                                            
   <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"                                                                                
     (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null;isSomeSelected()"                                                                               
     [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">                                                                           
 </mat-checkbox></td>
```